# How to set proper path configuration in Windows?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP for my website. In one of my configuration files I'm defining a constant as follows:

```
define('CORE_PATH',      BASE_PATH.'\core');
```

In another file I'm using this constant in a filepath configuration as follows:

```
require_once( CORE_PATH."\functions\common.php" );
```

But it's not working it's taking as 
`C:\wamp\www\smart-rebate-web\coreunctions\common.php instead` of

```
C:\wamp\www\smart-rebate-web\core\functions\common.php
```

I'm not getting mhy this is happening and how to make this thing correct so that the proper path should set in confgiuration file?
The value of CORE_PATH constant is as below:

```
C:\wamp\www\smart-rebate-web\core
```

Than ks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with replacing this:

```
require_once( CORE_PATH."\functions\common.php" );
```

with this:

```
require_once( CORE_PATH.'\functions\common.php' );
```

The reason is that your string is with double quotes, and inside double quotes, `\f` means formfeed (hex 0C), according to the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php). At the same time, `\c` isn't a special sequence, so the end result is `unctions\common.php`. Combined with your `CORE_PATH`, it results in `C:\wamp\www\smart-rebate-web\coreunctions\common.php`.

Tip: Use double-quotes strings only when you are sure you need them - interpolating variables, special sequences, SQL code, etc. They can ruin your day if you miss something unwanted in them. Also, when dealing with system paths, it's best to use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `/` or `\`. This way you can easily migrate from one platform to another without having to refactor your code.

Cheers.